# how to click play button amazon photos python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click the play button on amazon photos using selenium in a python script. I've tried using a xpath

```
play_button_displayed = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="photos"]/section/section/section/div/div/figure[1]/div/div[1]/figure/figure/button')

play_button_display.click()
```

i've tried other methods and the most promising in my eyes was the css selector
`

```
play_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".play")
play_button.click()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pictures_backup\tool_used\python\amazon_photos_web_list_creation\amazon_photos_open_and_replace_date_auto_and_manual\amazon_photos_open_and_replace_date_auto_and_manual.py", line 104, in <module>
    LaunchBrowser_main()
  File "d:\pictures_backup\tool_used\python\amazon_photos_web_list_creation\amazon_photos_open_and_replace_date_auto_and_manual\amazon_photos_open_and_replace_date_auto_and_manual.py", line 53, in LaunchBrowser_main
    click_info()
  File "d:\pictures_backup\tool_used\python\amazon_photos_web_list_creation\amazon_photos_open_and_replace_date_auto_and_manual\amazon_photos_open_and_replace_date_auto_and_manual.py", line 92, in click_info
    play_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"play")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 830, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"play"}
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.78)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x007C37D3]
    (No symbol) [0x00758B81]
    (No symbol) [0x0065B36D]
    (No symbol) [0x0068D382]
    (No symbol) [0x0068D4BB]
    (No symbol) [0x006C3302]
    (No symbol) [0x006AB464]
    (No symbol) [0x006C1215]
    (No symbol) [0x006AB216]
    (No symbol) [0x00680D97]
    (No symbol) [0x0068253D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A3ABF2+2510930]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A68EC1+2700065]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00A6C86C+2714828]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00873480+645344]
    (No symbol) [0x00760FD2]
    (No symbol) [0x00766C68]
    (No symbol) [0x00766D4B]
    (No symbol) [0x00770D6B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x761E00F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77607BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77607B8E+238]


[Done] exited with code=1 in 32.94 seconds
```

but that didn't work either. i would like to preferable work in css selector since that seems the easiest. any help will be much appreciated.

here's the xpath of buttom from chrome

```
//*[@id="photos"]/section/section/section/div/div/figure[1]/div/div[1]/figure/figure/button
```

full xpath

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/section/section/section/div/div/figure[1]/div/div[1]/figure/figure/button
```

and element

```
<button class="play"></button>
```

i've tried, xpath, css selector, class name id ect and they all didn't work but css selector seems the easiest and promising but thats not working lmao

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium ok  i updated with relevant html

Answer (score 0):

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#photos button.play"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='photos']/section/section/section/div/div/figure[1]/div/div[1]/figure/figure/button[@class='play']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: i tried this method and didn't work. I also tried using the xpath locator and css selector you provided for the way i tried and that didn't work as well @undetected Selenium